# QML Message Dialog on multiple screens in Windows

Tags: qt, qml

Can Anyone explain how QML MessageDialog gets the window reference to show the Dialog?

On my project, I have multiple screens support, and when I click in a button, the MessageDialog needs to show one to each monitor, but all of the MessageDialogs were shown at the monitor that clicked.

This happens only in Windows. On Linux, It works normally.

The example bellow is the QML part of the code. I have 2  different instances of the ApplicationWindow, but with different identificators, defined on cpp file. On windows, all MessageDialogs appears in one ApplicationWindow.

Did anyone had this problem too? How did you solved it?

```
AplicationWindow {
      id: appWind
      objectName: "app-wind"

      MessageDialog {
           id: messageDialog
           modality: Qt.WindowModal
           visible: false

           OnAccepted {
               console.log("Accept")
           }

           OnRejected {
               console.log("Reject")
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: I won't be able to help you, since I have only one monitor. However others might help you, if you provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example - so some code that reproduces your problem, can be copied and tried without modification, and does not contain massive amounts of unrelated statements.

Comment: I edited the question, with a simple snippet.